# Lua: How can I concatenate methods, as with the string methods?

Tags: methods, lua, concatenation

The string funtions can used with this ways:

```
string.FUNCTION('myString', PARAMETER)
```

or replace 'string' with the string to use and call it as method

```
('myString'):METHOD(PARAMETER)
```

The last way is very fine to read and allows to concatenate methods.

```
-- example string operation
some_str, pos = '   some string', 1
-- default string syntax
while string.find(string.sub(some_str, pos, pos), '%s') do pos = pos +1 end
-- the same with syntactic sugar
while some_str:sub(pos, pos):find('%s') do pos = pos +1 end
```

So I tried to get the same behaviour with my own functions. But this fails.
The only way I found, was to use an additional parameter to say: return the object itself or the result.
Here a simple example for this.

```
calc = {
    result = 0,
    operator = '',
    run = function(self, a, b, r) -- return self with r='s'
        if b == 's' then r, b = b, nil end
        if not b then b, a = a, self.result end
        if self.operator == '+' then self.result = (a) + (b)
        elseif self.operator == '-' then self.result = (a) - (b)
        elseif self.operator == '*' then self.result = (a) * (b)
        elseif self.operator == '/' then self.result = (a) / (b) end
        if r ~= nil then return self else return self.result end
    end,
    add = function(self, a, b, r) self.operator = '+' return self:run(a, b, r) end,
    sub = function(self, a, b, r) self.operator = '-' return self:run(a, b, r) end,
    mul = function(self, a, b, r) self.operator = '*' return self:run(a, b, r) end,
    div = function(self, a, b, r) self.operator = '/' return self:run(a, b, r) end
}

-- single operation
result = calc:add(12, 5)

-- concatenated operations
result = calc:add(12, 5, 's'):sub(3, 's'):mul(2, 's'):div(7)
```

Exists any way to do it same like in string operations? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lua returns a new string, and then you can simply call methods of the new string. Hence the chaining. Are you returning the same table that the method was called against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subsequent calls assign `'s'` to `b` parameter, not to `r`. Of course check for `return self` fails. Rather than give different behaviour to methods with some flags make them always `return self` instead and make a separate method to return current result - it will be much cleaner to read and program.

After that your call will look like:

```
result = calc:new(12):add(5):sub(3):mul(2):div(7):result()
```

Also, you don't really need proxy functions that go into one big function that splits into `if`s anyway - just do everything inside `add`/`sub`/`mul`/`div` themselves.

You'll probably want more than one calc object as well, with each one having its own separate current result. Store common functions in a metatable and make `:new` create new instances with this metatable and separate entry for result.

```
local calc_meta = { __index = {
    add = function(self, number) self._r = self._r + number return self end,
    sub = function(self, number) self._r = self._r - number return self end,
    mul = function(self, number) self._r = self._r * number return self end,
    div = function(self, number) self._r = self._r / number return self end,
    result = function(self) return self._r end
}}

local calc = {
    new = function(self, number)
    return setmetatable({
        _r = number or 0
    }, calc_meta) end
}

result = calc:new(12):add(5):sub(3):mul(2):div(7):result()
print(result)
-- 4
```

You can't completely duplicate Lua's behavior with strings - it is built-in into VM to treat `string` table as metatable for string values and cannot be programmed without modifying VM itself. You can get rid of extra `result` at end though if you add `__add`/`__sub` and other numeric methods to metatable so they would automatically "unwrap" your object to basic number value. Of course you won't be able to apply your methods to "unwrapped" value after that.

Comment: >Your subsequent calls assign 's' to b parameter, not to r< I know, because that i check if given parameter b is 's' and swap it with r. But it was only an example. You'r right, it can be solved with seperate methode to return the result. But I'm interested: How is it solved in the string library? There is the result the same as the object itself. You can cover any string and use it as object for the string methods. Its graetfull, but how it works?

Comment: @McBarby, it's Lua VM built-in, you can't completely duplicate that. Expanded answer.